# How to find system output by its step response?

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, digital-filters, filtering, step-response

Inspired by [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/17035/how-to-find-the-output-of-a-system-with-the-unit-step-response-and-the-input) post, I tried to reproduce the procedure described in the answer in `Python` considering rectangular pulse:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.arange(-1, 1, 1e-3)
N = len(t)

x = np.ones(N)
plt.plot(t, x)
```

[image: Input signal]

and exponential step response:

```
A = 1
tau = 100e-3

def step_response(t, A, tau):
    return 1+A*np.exp(-t/tau)

a = step_response(t, A, tau)
```

[image: Step response]

According to the answer, rewriting the input sequence as:

```
x_new = []
for i,j in enumerate(t):
    temp_data = 0
    for m in range(1,len(t)):
        temp_data += x[m]-x[m-1]*u[i-m]
    temp_data += x[-1]
    x_new.append(temp_data)
```

which gives:

[image: rewritten input signal]

and finally, the output signal $y[n]$:

```
y = []
for i,j in enumerate(t):
    temp_data = 0
    for m in range(1,len(t)):
        temp_data += x[m]-x[m-1]*a[i-m]
    temp_data += x[-1]*a[-1]
    y.append(temp_data)
```

[image]

The result looks strange, maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Why don't you just define a new signal as the first order difference of the input signal, and then use a convolution function to convolve it with the step response?

Comment: what do you mean by "first order difference"? just simple difference? could ypu please clarify it)

Comment: The first order difference is $x[k]-x[k-1]$.

Comment: if I do so, I think it is evident, that the new signal will be zero-signal (because initially it is $1$ everywhere), does it make sense?

Comment: No, it is non-zero at two points: namely when the input goes from zero to its first non-zero value, and when it goes back to zero at the end. I'll write a quick Octave script and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the answer linked to by the OP, in discrete time, the output can be computed by convolving the step response with the first-order difference of the input sequence. If we assume that the system is causal and that the input sequence starts at $n=0$ we have

$$y[n]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\big(x[k]-x[k-1]\big)a[n-k],\qquad n\ge 0$$

(with $x[-1]=0$).

Here is a little Matlab/Octave script computing the output using the step response and comparing it with the output computed using the impulse response. Of course, both methods give the same result, up to numerical accuracy.

```
% implement filter using step response
L = 50;
n = (0:L-1)';
a = (.7).^n;                    % step response
x = [ones(10,1);zeros(L-10,1)]; % input
xd = diff( [0; x] );            % first-order difference of input
y = conv( xd, a );

% compare with convolution with impulse response
h = diff( [0; a] );
y_ = conv( x, h );
```

[image]

Comment: just the last question: why do you start finding the difference (diff function) from the second sample?

Comment: @Curious: It's actually the opposite, I start from one sample before $x[k]$ actually starts, in order to include the jump from zero to the first value $x[0]$. So the first sample in the difference equals $x[0]-x[-1]$ with $x[-1]=0$.

Comment: am I right, the need to find the difference here is the same as taking derivative of the input signal? I just didn't completely get the idea of doing it

Comment: In continuous time it would be the derivative, in discrete time there is no derivative. The first-order difference plays the role of the derivative in this case.

Comment: thank you so much!)